# Angular , Ionic - parsing whitespace in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

How would you handle a json like 
`{ 
  "FULLNAME" : "John Smith", 
   "USERNAME  :  "John_Smith"
 }`

In ionic it gives me a blank when I try to print it out `{{FULLNAME)}}` in a view/html , unless I remove the space in "John Smith"
staffMember.FULLNAME - returns nothing
All though when you view the staffMember object, you can see "John Smith"

Tried a heck lot of functions such as `parse`, `toString` ,  returns with `[0bject] [0bject]`
--- part of my code below ---
Data gets returned from Firebase . everything else prints fine except for staffMember.FULLNAME

```
        <!-- Friend Name, Status Icon and Status Update -->
        <div class="gem-friend-list-text">
        <!-- thumb image (round) -->
        <img src="img/gemionic/profile-image.jpg" alt="" class="gem-friend-list-profile-pic"> <!-- End Image - absolute left/top -->

          <b>{{staffMember.USERNAME}}</b>
          <b>{{staffMember.ADDRESS}}</b>
          <b>{{staffMember.ALTERNATECONTACTNO}}</b>
          <b>{{staffMember.EMAIL}}</b>
          <b>{{staffMember.FULLNAME}}</b>  
           <b>{{staffMember.JOINDATE}}</b>


          <span class="signature"><i class="icon ion-record" ng-class="staffMember.STATUS=='Active'
         ? 'gem-color-success' : 'gem-color-default'"  ></i> {{staffMember.STATUS}} | "Last SignIn Date" | {{staffMember.LASTSEENDATE}}    </span>
          <!-- gem-color-default
          gem-color-danger -->
        </div></a>
        <!-- end -->
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

P.S. : I have even done - console.log('staffMember Name: ' + staffMember.FULLNAME); - it returns as undefined.
console.log('staff username ' + staffMember.USERNAME); this returns as expected "JOHN_SMITH"

Comment: post some of your code

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` will do the trick

Comment: @pankaj - that didnt work  
 
JSON.stringify(obj) - just gives me a blank however - toString(staffMember.FULLNAME) returns with [object] [object]

Comment: @Yohannes - posted some of my code from the view.html, thanks for all the help. this problem has   given me sleepless nights.

Comment: Hoping Someone can help Me out with this - Has me boggled for the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the struggle you're having is probably that your content above is not actually valid JSON. Maybe you meant something more like this?

```
{ "FULLNAME" : "John Smith"}
```

There is still more to answer, once you have this in a variable you can put the variable on the scope and so on. But hopefully this helps get you moving in the right direction. Good luck.